# overriding save method to save ip address in django models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a Django project and I need to save the user's IP address in my database.

I can get user's ip address with `request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")`.

Currently, I have to provide an IP address in my save and edit views. I was looking for a clean solution so that I can override the models `save()` method and let models save IP address every time a new record is added or any record is updated.

But Django models don't have access to `request`.

Is there any workaround for this? or do I have to provide an IP address in my every saves and edits view.

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question, you should try this;

```
ip_address = request.META.get("REMOTE_ADDR")
your_model.objects.create(ip_address=ip_address)
```

This will create a new entry in your model(here represented by `your_model`). Note that you need to provide all the columns present in your model. Here i am only showing the ip_address in the parenthesis but if you model also stores username(say) then you also need to provide that.
E.g,

```
your_model.objects.create(username= your_username, ip_address=ip_address)
```

Comment: yeah, I know this approach. But I was looking for a better way to hand over ip saving thing to my models. So that I don't have to explicitly define ip address in every view each time a record is inserted or updated.